# Java API for KML / gx:Track

Tags: kml, google-earth, jak

I've been trying to figure out how to create a gx:Track with the current version of the Java API for KML.  Even though JAK claims to support the latest 2.2 extensions, the kml22gx.xsd that is packaged with the source code does not match the [actual latest](https://developers.google.com/kml/schema/kml22gx.xsd?csw=1).

Can someone detail the build process for taking new XSD's and generating a new jak?

Answer (score 0):

I got the jar from someone on Google Groups, here it is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1Y3FuLhrOkHdDRNNTlpaGJuQTg/edit?usp=sharing

(PS I may have made some little changes)

Comment: Given that this is a production project, I can't just start including random jars from the internet.  I appreciate it (and I'll fool around with this one), but I'd at least need the source as well.

Comment: "production" is a strong word. This project, although a good one, is abandonware. Feel free not to use this jar, I won't get offended.

Comment: By the way, jar decompilers work quite well http://sourceforge.net/projects/jadclipse/

Comment: Finally, building jak from schema involved way more than just using XSD, they used Perl scripts to do customizations, it wasn't pretty

Comment: If it's abandoneware, then I may consider taking control of it, moving it to GitHub, and updating it myself.  There's quite a bit of documentation on their website about how they did it... there's just nobody home anymore, and I can't find a better KML library for Java.

Comment: That would be wonderful. Mind the KML specs hardly ever change, other than gx:tracks I can't remember anything else they've changed. I've made little changes by hand myself, I can package the source for you

Comment: By the way, something I've found about reducing memory usage with JAK, you may be interested in case you needed to deal with a large number of features https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/javaapiforkml/CJG-WHEoo8A

Comment: Sorry, just had a tought, let's create a community on GitHub. I'm in favour of giving Commit access to anybody who sends pull requests

Comment: I'll setup a community on GitHub and post the URL here tonight (East Coast, US).   For starters it will just be the existing source from JAK's svn repo.  We can move out from there.  I haven't used github much, so I'll make you a co-admin.

Comment: I sent an e-mail to info@micromata.de letting them know our intentions.  I figured that would at least be the polite thing to do.

Comment: Cool! github.com/ZiglioNZ/

Comment: https://github.com/flevine100/JavaAPIForKML - Having never run a GitHub repo, forgive me if it's not setup right.  I added you as a collaborator.

Comment: Thanks for that. Hopefully tomorrow I'll import the SVN history from the Google Code project. Then I'll create a branch for gx:track and another branch with my other changes

Comment: I added this, although JAK seems somewhat abandoned -- https://github.com/micromata/javaapiforkml/issues/3

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize they still didn't have gx:Track! See https://github.com/flevine100/JavaAPIForKML-DELETE/tree/gxtrack/src/main/java/de/micromata/opengis/kml/v_2_2_0/gx